# Can't fetch item from current slug content- Sanity/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, slug, sanity

I'm trying to get the `set_name` from the `set` schema that is associated to the current slug. `*[_type == 'set']{set_name, slug}` is how the schema looks. I'm not getting the `set_name` when I click on the slug however, and my console isn't showing any errors.

```
const sets = (setData) => {
  return ( 
    <div> 
      <Header />
      <main className="slug-gallery"> 
        <div className='title'>
          <h2>{setData.set_name}</h2>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
}
export default sets;

export const getServerSideProps = async (pageContext) => {
  const setSlug = pageContext.query.slug;

  const setQuery = `*[_type == 'set' && slug.current == $setSlug][0]`;
  const setData = await client.fetch(setQuery, {setSlug})

  return {
    props: {setData}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Just needed to do: `const sets = ({setData}) => {`